# How to gracefully shutdown a thread in C

Tags: c, winapi

I have something like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI test(LPVOID lpParam) {
    while (1) {
        /*DO STUFF*/
    }
}

int main() {
    ...
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,test,NULL,0,&dwThreadId);
    ...
}
```

How can i shutdown the Thread without TerminateThread()? 
My first idea was creating a global variable (shouldshutdown = 0/1), set it in the main() when the Thread should shutdown. Then call ExitThread() in the Thread. Therefore i have to check for this variable in the while loop of the thread which is bad style i guess.

Comment: How will the thread know it has to return?

Comment: @2501 He doesnt. Thats the problem. I have to implement something like a check in the loop - i want to avoid this.

Comment: @Kntlii Well, a conditional is unavoidable.

Comment: Can you avoid this by designing around it?  If you are only trying to shutdown becasue you want to terminate your process, then the first approach, always, is to not do it.  Only terminate threads explicitly if it is unavoidable.  The OS is MUCH better at stopping threads than your user code.

Comment: @MartinJames: And then, the OS is **MUCH** worse at guessing, what cleanup your user code should perform.

Comment: @IInspectable 'if it is unavoidable' :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You an event that the thread can check to see if it needs to stop. For example (without error handling):

```
DWORD WINAPI test(LPVOID lpParam) 
{
    HANDLE hEvent = (HANDLE)lpParam

    while (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT) 
    {
        /*DO STUFF*/
    }
}

int main() {
    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL)
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,test,(LPVOID)hEvent,0,&dwThreadId);
    // Do
    // Stuff
    // Tell the thread to exit
    SetEvent(hEvent)

    // Wait for the thread to exit
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}
```

The general pattern is to give the thread some sort of alertable object that it can monitor and something else can set. In this case I've used a manual reset event. The `while` loop checks to see if the event has been signaled, and if not it does stuff. When it is signaled then `WaitForSingleObject` will return `WAIT_OBJECT_0` and the loop will exit and you'll fall out of the thread function.

In the main function all you need to do after signalling the event is wait for the thread to exit.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to use the [interlocked variable access functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx) than an event object.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - sure, but then you lose the ability to wait on the exit event, which may also be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send messages between your main thread and your worker threads - for example the work to do consists of tasks that you are placing on some queue, the simplest option might be to simply simply give the worker thread a message loop.

The `PostThreadMessage` API can be used to post `WM_APP` messages to the thread with tasks to perform, and a `WM_QUIT` message when the thread should exit. This saves you building your own thread safe signalling mechanisms.

It has the side benefit that, if your worker thread is instantiating COM objects, all you need to do is add an initial call to `CoInitialize` and the thread is a valid STA.

Comment: Any thread that uses COM **must** call `CoInitialize/Ex()` anyway.  But a thread does not need to use COM to create a message loop for itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shutdown a thread you have two options:
1. Force the thread to terminate (with TerminateThread).
2. Ask the thread to shutdown (for this to work the thread has to cooperate).

If you choose the second option you have some choices about how to do it. One choice is to use a global flag to tell the thread to terminate (I'm not sure why you think that is bad style). The best choice will probably depend on what your thread is doing.